# Why does TIMEOUT no longer wait as stated?

Tags: cmd

I originally posted this on Microsoft Answer Community website but got told they don't deal with this sort of question. (Funny, as I suspect it's a bug in one of their `cmd.exe` commands or some related thing.)

Suddenly Windows 11 command `TIMEOUT` is failing for me in a `CMD` file. It doesn't wait the prescribed time.

E.g. `TIMEOUT /T 8` reports the starting seconds for countdown and *immediately* exits.

I found out with debugging that this does *not* occur if I manually enter it into a `CMD.EXE` window prompt. Further testing shows that the first call of `TIMEOUT` in a `CMD` file actually fails, subsequent ones work as documented. My current circumvention is to code a `TIMEOUT /T 1` at the start of the `CMD` file to ensure the 'real' ones behave.

A simple batch file demonstrates the effect (on my machine at least).

Batch file saved as `test.CMD` in my case:

```
echo on 
timeout.exe /T 8 
echo. 
echo now invoking with full path ...
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 8 
echo. 
echo now invoking choice ... 
choice /T 8 /C Y /D Y /M "Press Y to continue (or wait for timeout)"
echo. 
echo do a PAUSE so you can see the results on the screen before batch file finishes running
PAUSE
```

I double-clicked on this batch file after saving it to run it. The first call of `timeout` fails, the second seems to always work. Doesn't matter if you put the full path on the `timeout.exe` command or not, nor in what order.

Anyone else encountered this problem?

I have only been able to find the circumvention I mentioned above.

---

Output of some commands for information about the execution environment:

```
set path
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\lorde\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query HKCU\Environment /v Path
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    Path    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe timeout
C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe

%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but even if I had an available Windows 11 PC to test this on, I wouldn't. The reason for this is that I would only ever use the second, full path, command: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 8```. My `test.CMD` would therefore consist of only two lines, and be run directly from a Command Prompt window, like this: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K "test.CMD"```. Its entire content would be: **1.** ```%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 8```, **2.** ```%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 7```.

Comment: I can not reproduce it with a fresh installed win 11 (`Version 10.0.22621.525`)

Comment: My Windows reports as -

Windows 11 Home
Version 22H2
Installed on 12/11/22
OS build 22621.1413

Comment: I recommend to click on Windows __Start__ button, type now on keyboard `environ` and click on suggested item __Edit the system environment variables__, click on button __Environment Variables...__, double click on __system variable__ `Path` in the lower list of environment variables and click several times on button __Move Down__ to move the first folder path of Java below the last Windows default folder path ``%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH\``. However, the execution environment is well defined.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue with a `Test.cmd` with just the two lines `timeout /T 8` and `timeout /T 8` on `Windows 11 Version 22H2 (OS Build 22621.1265)` (output of `winver.exe`) respectively `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1265]` (output of `cmd` command `ver`). The two `timeout` run perfect on opening a command prompt window and run `test.cmd` with current directory containing the batch file `test.cmd`. But a double click on the batch file in Windows File Explorer results in first `timeout` exiting immediately after output of `Waiting for 8 seconds, press a key to continue ...`.

Comment: The usage of `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 8` makes not difference. There is nevertheless the first `timeout` immediately exited even on starting the batch file with a double click in Total Commander instead of Windows File Explorer. A solution is using on first `timeout` additionally `/NOBREAK`. Another solution is using as first line in the batch file `set /p "Dummy="` and hit __RETURN__ to continue batch file processing without variable definition. I cannot even see with Windows Sysinternals *Process Monitor* why running the batch file with a double click causes that difference.

Comment: The batch file execution is started with execution of `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Temp\Test.cmd" "` on double click on *Windows File Explorer* or *Total Commander* (64-bit version) or just hitting key __RETURN__ in *Total Commander* with file `Test.cmd` selected in active pane. The execution of exactly the same command line in an already opened command prompt window results in counting down eight seconds by both `timeout`. Copying `Test.cmd` to another PC with Windows 7 and double clicking on the batch file on Windows 7 results in both `timeout` executing as expected.

Comment: I copied now `C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe` of Windows 7 to `C:\Temp` on Windows 11, edited the batch file to run twice `C:\Temp\timeout.exe /T 8` and could see that on double click of the batch file the first `timeout` again exits immediately while running the batch file from within a command prompt window results in both `timeout` counting down the eight seconds. BTW: There is visible only the seconds value in console window on running `timeout.exe` of Windows 7 on Windows 11. `Waiting for ` and `seconds, press a key to continue ...` is not visible with `timeout.exe` of Win 7 on Win 11.

Comment: `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /M Test:` as first line in `Test.cmd` executed with a double click on Windows 11 does not result in error noise as done on pressing a wrong key. The first `timeout` command works after `choice` exited after pressing key __Y__ or __N__. That is indeed a very strange issue of `cmd.exe` on Windows 11 22H2 or of the console API functions of Windows 11 22H2. The immediate exit of first `timeout` is definitely not explainable for me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me today what I did was add a /nobreak which for some reason does work. If you may afford to not skip the waiting time by hitting a key.

(Windows 11, 22h2, build 22621.1413)

Comment: Thanks for that info, will remember for future use when ok to not skip wait time.